# Docker Laravel Storage Permission Error

Tags: php, linux, laravel, docker

I have a Docker container running a PHP Laravel app. The docker image can be found at: https://hub.docker.com/r/niaquinto/laravel/. When I go to the app in the browser, I get the following error: `file_put_contents(/share/app/storage/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied` Screenshot: http://d.pr/i/1327m

**I've tried:**

1. I've updated the 1000 user to give www-data ownership over the storage directory with `usermod -u 1000 www-data`. The current permissions for `app/storage` look like:

---

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data staff 102 Dec  9 04:34 cache 
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data staff 102 Dec  9 04:34 debugbar 
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data staff 136 Dec 16 16:29 logs 
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data staff 102 Dec 16 19:08 meta 
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data staff 102 Dec  9 04:34 sessions 
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data staff 272 Dec 16 16:29 views
```

2. I've tried updating the perms with chmod, but they don't take.
3. I've tried clearing the cache after this with: `php artisan cache:clear`
4. I've tried `composer dump-autoload`
5. I've tried running `php artisan clear-compiled` and `php artisan serve`

I'm familiar with Docker but less familiar with Lavarel so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to execute chmod -R 777 /share/app/storage

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @PabloDigiani. I ran that and cleared the cache via artisan and still getting same error. Here is the perms for storage after that: `drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data staff 306 Dec  9 04:34 share/app/storage`

Comment: The desired perms are: drwxrwxrwx. It seems that you need to run the command again using sudo:
sudo chmod -R 777 /share/app/storage
Then check if perms have changed.

Comment: @PabloDigiani I ran with sudo, no change: http://d.pr/i/EoNa. Weird, right?